# How to filter the ManyToMany of a queryset in django

Tags: python, django, many-to-many, django-queryset

I have two models, questions and their answers, and I want to fetch **ALL questions** along with a **single answer** to them, i.e, the answer which has the **maximum count** of upvoters for that question. How do I fetch this result in a Queryset(I'll be paginating the result so having a queryset will ease the process)

```
class Question(models.Model):
    question = models.CharField(max_length = 128)
    asker = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete = models.CASCADE, related_name="asked_questions")
    requested = models.ManyToManyField(CustomUser, related_name="answer_requests")
    followers = models.ManyToManyField(CustomUser, related_name="followed_questions")
    topics = models.ManyToManyField(Topic, related_name="questions")
    url = models.CharField(max_length = 150)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True, blank = True)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.question

class Answer(models.Model):
    answer = models.TextField()
    author = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete = models.CASCADE, related_name="written_answers")
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete = models.CASCADE, related_name="answers")
    upvoters = models.ManyToManyField(CustomUser, related_name="upvoted_answers")
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True, blank = True)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try like this using [**`subquery expression`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/expressions/#subquery-expressions)

```
from django.db.models import Count, Subquery, OuterRef

answer_subquery = Answer.objects.filter(question=OuterRef('pk')).annotate(upvotes=Count('upvoters')).order_by('-upvotes')

questions = Question.objects.annotate(answer=Subquery(answer_subquery.values('answer')[:1]))
```

Comment: Super helpful. Thank you so much !